# In which elastic stack version the watcher is introduced?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have `Elastic stack (6.8.0)` free version. But I cannot use watcher features there as mentioned in the following link.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.6/watcher-ui.html

Simply I don't have a section `"Management > Elasticsearch > Watcher"`. I'm planning to upgrade `Elastic stack to 7.5.2` free version. Will I have watcher feature there?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Alerting features (Watcher) are not free in any version, you need at least a `gold` license subscription to use it, that's why you are not seeing it in your kibana interface.

You can see the difference between the licenses subscriptions in [this link](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions)